# Wordpress Wp bakery loads background image continuosly

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

The wpbakery background images are keep on loading. Please find the below screenshots for reference.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCBsb.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JSdD.png)

Comment: Have you purchased the wpbakery plugin?

Comment: I have not purchased. It came under the theme.

Comment: Can you share me issue URL? If possible?

Comment: url: https://marathon-inc.net/